# How to log in to my Google-Signin'd Stack Exchange without Google signin?

Tags: discussion, openid

I created a Stack Overflow account with Google Signin. Sometimes I'm on another computer where I don't want to sign in to Google, but I do want to log in to my SO account. Is there any way to do that? Any way to configure my SO account so I can sign in either with Google or with a username/password?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Head over to your profile, click on My Logins & click on Add More logins.

[image]

Now, at the login page, login with another openID provider, or create a Stack Exchange account. You'll be able to login to your account using the selected openID provider or using Stack Exchange account

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. Sorry I don't have the rep to up-vote you.

Comment: @ChrisPhoenix that's quite alright :)